# Get the count of the first column in multiple sheets and display them in separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, countif

I'm dealing with Excel VLOOKUP and COUNTIF that gets the count of number of entries in first column of every sheet and display the results in separate sheet accordingly with the product

Example:

I have 4 sheets in excel (4 sheet related to 4 products say oldnavy/purell/BB/Macys)

Each sheet has multiple columns.

Im looking to get just get the count of number of rows in first column for all 4 sheets and place in fift sheet with product name in each row and count of it

```
Tried using VLOOKUP and COUNTIF
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to dynamically reference worksheets, you need to use `INDIRECT()`.
If, in `Sheet5` you have your worksheet names "oldnavy/purell/BB/Macys" in `A1:A4` respectively, then in cell `B1` you could put

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!A:A"))
```

And drag it down. `COUNTA` counts all non-blank cells in a range.

Comment: Tried this im getting 1 as count @Tate Garringer

Comment: Generally that means that it's throwing a `#REF` error for what you're trying to reference. The values in `A1:A4` Will have to match the names of the worksheets otherwise it'll throw that error.

Comment: Hi @Tate Garringer see the pics -- first pic where i got summary of counts and second pic is the first coulum of every sheet
 https://ibb.co/7SVRmxh
https://ibb.co/qYyHWwt

Comment: Edited the answer to accommodate worksheets with spaces in the name.

Comment: Hello Thanks Much it worked everysheet except first sheet(sheet which i shared in the pic2) weird..also can we ignore the header im expecting count without header (the heading of the column A1) @Tate Garringer

Comment: `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!A:A")) - 1` will ignore the header row. If the first sheet is still giving you trouble, it's a discrepancy between the name of the worksheet and what's in the cell checking against it. You might try copy and pasting the worksheet name into the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, do this:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,"<>")
```

I believe you understand `COUNTIF()`

Condition `"<>"` basically means *'not equal to empty/nothing'*, so *'count all that is not empty'*

Hope that helps

Comment: Note this will count zero 0 values, as 0 <> "".
You can use `COUNTIFS()` with an extra condition for that.

Comment: Hello its asking to open another sheet...all my sheets are in single excel.i have input the formule against oldnavy and dragged for rest